# Event Emitter memory leak because of ReactJS Rerendering

Tags: node.js, reactjs, electron, eventemitter

I hope you're having a nice day ✌ Thanks for helping in advance.

I'm building a web browser with ElectronJS and React. I'm using ipcMain and ipcRenderer to send events between the backend and the frontend, they're just children of the EventEmitter class.

The issue I'm dealing with is EventEmitter leaks. My React frontend sends an event, and the backend returns data. React then assigns this data to it's state which causes a re-render which then creates another event listener. This creates a bunch of event listeners and then I get memory leak errors.

This is an example of my React component

```
export const CoreLayout = props => {

  const [tablist, setTablist] = useState([]);
  window.ipcRenderer.on('receive-tabs', (_, data) => {
    setTablist(data);
  });

  console.log('rerender2')

  return (
    <div className="flex flex-col w-full min-h-screen bg-night-600">
      <Header tablist={tablist} isMaximized={props.isMaximized} />
    </div>
  )

}
```

Comment: you should use `useEffect` to manage subscriptions like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  useEffect(()=>{
    const listener= (_, data) => {
      setTablist(data);
    };
    window.ipcRenderer.on('receive-tabs', listener);
    
    return ()=>{
      window.ipcRenderer.removeListener('receive-tabs', listener);
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 4):

For implementing side effects in `render`, you should always consider `useEffect`. In your case, when the component ends its lifecycle (is unmounted), you'll usually want to remove the event listener.

See https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#effects-with-cleanup for instructions how to set up a side effect with an automatic clean-up. To avoid re-running this on each render, you'll want an empty dependency array, as described here in the big, yellow Note section: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#tip-optimizing-performance-by-skipping-effects

> If you want to run an effect and clean it up only once (on mount and unmount), you can pass an empty array ([]) as a second argument. This tells React that your effect doesn’t depend on any values from props or state, so it never needs to re-run.

Comment: Just looked into it, I needed it to remove all event listeners on re-render instead of on unmount. I was able to do that by just adding the function to remove the event listener at the beginning of the function, that way it removed the old event listeners on every render and created new ones.